# What is this chip in a switching power supply marked 1ADJM?

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, identification

I'm trying to identify a chip, possibly a switch, used in a switching power supply.

It's 6-pin, and marked **1ADJM** (or maybe **IADJM**)

[image]

Comment: The picture is not very helpful, as it does not show the surroundings at all, to see the pinout which is input, output, or ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [MP1470 step down converter](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp1470.html) from MPS.

Datasheet [here](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP1470/document_id/327/).